# Search in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to get this code to work, but for some reason I'm getting compile error

```
   private IQueryable<T> FindObjects(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, T item)
    {
        using (MainEntities mainEntities = new MainEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                return mainEntities.CreateObjectSet().Where(predicate);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                throw new Exception(ErrorHelper.GenerateExceptionMessage(exp));
            }
        };
    }
```

Complile Error:
The type arguments for method 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `T` is an entity type, you need:

```
return mainEntities.CreateObjectSet<T>().Where(predicate);
```

(By the way: re-throwing a new exception obscures the original exception for the calling code. At least make it the InnerException of the new Exception).